# In WSL (SuSE flavor), setpgid on child fails due to rights?

Tags: linux, bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Running in bash on current OpenSuSE Leap 42.3 WSL on Windows 10 Fall Creators Update:

```
echo $PATH | perl  -pe 's{/mnt/[cd].+?:}{}g'
```

fails with

```
-bash: child setpgid (198 to 197): Operation not permitted
```

if executed as **normal user**. However, running with sudo, it works. This command line appears very basic, shouldn't it work in a normal bash environment as user?

Comment: Same here, but... "for i in * ; do /bin/echo x|cat ; done" works; "for i in * ; do echo x|cat; done" fails with the same error, but the groups keep increasing! (only in bash - using another shell works)